# Prove $\frac{\sin(A+B)}{\cos(A-B)}=\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1+\tan A\tan B}$

Tags: trigonometry

How would I solve the following double angle identity. 
$$
\frac{\sin(A+B)}{\cos(A-B)}=\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1+\tan A\tan B}
$$
So far my work has been.
$$
\frac{\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B}{\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B}
$$
But what would I do to continue.

Comment: Divide numerator and denominator by $\cos A \cos B$.

Comment: Oh I see now dividing by cos I get the correct answer thanks to all who posted.

Comment: One can _prove_ and _identity_ or _solve_ an _equation_.  But to speak of _solving_ an _identity_ could leave some doubt about what you mean.

Comment: @Ross. Sorry about that. avatar's comment, your answer, and my edit came virtually on top of each other; I didn't see the notifications while I was editing. Note to self: for questions that are likely to be answered immediately after they're posted, delay editing until the dust settles.

Comment: @RickDecker:  No big problem.  I put it back.

Answer (score 8):

Now divide by $\cos A \cos B$ and you are there

Answer (score 2):

What i get is, **how to solve the problem**?? Is that correct then here u are:

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\sin x\cos y + \cos x\sin y}{\cos x\cos y}} {\dfrac{\cos x\cos y + \sin x\sin y}{\cos x\cos y}}$$

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\sin x\cos y}{\cos x\cos y} +\dfrac{\cos x\sin y}{\cos x\cos y}} {\dfrac{\cos x\cos y} {\cos x\cos y}+ \dfrac{\sin x\sin y}{\cos x\cos y}}$$
$$\dfrac{\tan x+\tan y}{1+\tan x\tan y}$$